# How to Clear data from customized Dialog in Android?

Tags: android

I'm wondering if it is possible to clear data from a customized dialog. I have a customized dialog having 5 textview and edittexts. I have two buttons named "Send " and "Clear" first is supposed to send the data to database and second is meant to clear the data, in case if user wants to re-enter the whole text there in the 5 edittext fields.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SIMPLE:**

You want to set the text of the editText to an empty string or "".

**IN DEPTH:**

You need to import:

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Make sure you have this below your onCreate:

```
EditText field1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText field2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
EditText field3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
EditText field4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
```

Onclick you want to:

```
field1 .setText("");
field2 .setText("");
field3 .setText("");
field4 .setText("");
```

**OVERKILL:**

Here is how I would do it:

```
//START OF CUSTOM ALERTDIALOG//

    void openCustomDialog(){
         AlertDialog.Builder customDialog 
          = new AlertDialog.Builder(ACTIVITYNAMEHERE.this);
         customDialog.setTitle("TITLE HERE");
         customDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action);

//OPTIONAL Enter custom layout here if you want
//LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
//=
//(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)//;
//View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout,null);

      customDialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               //CODE FOR DATABASE
           YOURACTIVITYHERE.this.finish();
       }});

      customDialog.setNegativeButton("Reset Fields", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

       public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       }});
     //CODE I PROVIDED up top
            field1 .setText("");
            field2 .setText("");
            field3 .setText("");
            field4 .setText("");
            customDialog.setView(view);
            customDialog.show();
        }




    //END OF CUSTOM ALERTDIALOG//
```

Comment: see my below comment. you mean to say i just have to do this setText(""); for v1...v5. Oh man! how stupid i was. Btw thanks @EDHDK

Comment: Yeah, I added code for an AlertDialog. It's a simple Send and Reset box. Added code for a custom layout if necessary. Look at what other methods are called (such as `finish()` Nice feature to have.

Glad my answer could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could extends "Dialog" class, retrieve the views and clear the data.

If you show your code, we could help you more.

Comment: Sorry i can't.But i got your point up-to retrieving the views and how about clearing the data then? e.g let us say on that button(clear) click i called the  clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { and here i retrived the views say v1,v2,v3..v5     Then what? };